# How is Git/SVN used for getting code from websites?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I'm not new to version control, but am new to version control through the internet. I'm sure there will be a lot of other newbies who are struggling the same way I am. I'm not familiar with the commandline approach mentioned by many here. I'm sure there are many more programmers who don't know how to do it because they don't know why it's relevant/helpful. Please help us understand, by answering this question.

First, I wanted to know why people checkout opensource files from the internet, when people can simply download and build the source locally.

I want to use Git to get the latest code from the VirtualPlanetBuilder website (I know how to download the zip source, and that's not what I'm asking).

There are many Git downloads [here](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list), but I want to know if any one of these is specifically meant for checking out files from the internet.

When I try clicking the Git-read-only link [here](https://github.com/openscenegraph/VirtualPlanetBuilder), I get an alert saying "Firefox does not know how to open this address because the protocol (git) is not associated with any program". I already have Git-1.7.11-preview20120620.exe installed, so what does this alert/error mean, and what should I do to get the source of VirtualPlanetBuilder on my disk?

Comment: It's more convenient to `git clone` from the command line than to download with Firefox and unzip the code, I take it you are not familiar with the command line?

Comment: The reason to checkout the sources instead of simply downloading them is that you can easily update them later and share your changes in the other way.

Comment: fundamental knowledge - git is run from the command line! :-) I recommend you go and read this book, if you want to know all about git. http://git-scm.com/book/  then go and grab a program called "git extensions" if you want to do git stuff from explorer (sometimes I prefer it with non code stuff... depends on what you're version controlling)

Comment: Why the downvote? This question is relevant, and will help a lot of other newbies who don't know what the rest of the world knows about open source (and about the commandline). Yes, I haven't used the commandline like how you mention.

Comment: PS grabbing a distribution from a git repository with git clone isn't really like checking out in SVN. it's essentially getting a copy of the entire repository on your own computer. distributed version control, yo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific version of Git for specific use cases. You simply need to [clone](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) the repository - which could be local to your network, your machine or on the internet.

Checking out code rather than downloading it would give you the advantage of being able to amend it and keep your changes tracked if you needed to. It'd also make it simpler to update your copy - `git fetch`, `git pull`.

From a command prompt:

`git clone https://github.com/openscenegraph/VirtualPlanetBuilder.git`

You'll probably want to look at getting a Git GUI for Windows though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157476/what-guis-exist-for-git-on-windows

Comment: I'm going to save you from reading "What GUIs exist for Git on Windows"... Install GitExtensions or TortoiseGit

Comment: actually msysgit will work quite well until he tries to figure out stuff like rebase and cherrypick 3rd and 7th last commit from xx branch, unless the user is already used to TortoiseSvn

Answer (score 1):

If you have msysgit correctly installed, you can simply open the command prompt and execute commands like:

```
git clone git://github.com/msysgit/git.git
```

Then to get into the source folder:

```
cd git
```

It shouldn't be any different for other git repositories.